# Android Studio tells me "The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'."

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

This looks like a false positive to me because my Flutter App all still builds, and why couldn't I assign a dynamic to a double? But because now literally all of my files are red, I don't want to ignore it. There are also a LOT of other error messages, such as `A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.`, `Missing type arguments for generic type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>'.` and many others that still work tho.

An example of code that doensn't work:

```
class Kpi{
  final String name;
  final double value;

  Kpi({this.type, this.name);

  factory Kpi.valuesFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Kpi(
       name: json['Key'],
       value: json['Value'].toDouble()
);
}
```

Here, name and value are red with the errormessage from the title.

Things I tried

- App restart
- Android studio restart
- Flutter clean
- PC (Mac) restart

This happened after tortoise checkouting to an old revision and changing back.

Additionally, a lot of warnings appeard like only using " " if the string has ' ', or this: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_constructors.html

Flutter Version

```
Flutter 1.22.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f30b7f4db9 (3 months ago) • 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
Engine • revision 75bef9f6c8
Tools • Dart 2.10.1
```

Comment: looks like your android studio cache has collapsed. Did you try invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan I did not know such thing could happen, nor how to fix it. How can I do this?

Comment: check File->Invalid Cache/Restart->Invalid And Restart in android studio menu

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan that didn't do it, sadly

Comment: please add `flutter --version` result and KPI class code

Comment: This has nothing to do with flutter version or android studio cache, this is a data type runtime error. What data types  are expected from Key and  Value?

Comment: You can't call .toDouble from a dynamic object/property, you must cast it first, but to cast you must guarantee the the cast type will succeed

Comment: @Kohls it used to work and it still works now, it just tells me that its an error. i know someplaces where i did (generic as class).classmethod(), but it used to work without it